# some regular expression or what is the best way to extract the "value" of an html tag <input> in python?

Tags: python

I have a string that contains several `html tags` with this form:

```
string= '<input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="7629b234d1cc2f2a5383f5e6d7dc6bd2">'
```

I would like to extract the `"value"`, I would do it with a `.split`, but I am not sure if it is the best way.

output desired:

```
7629b234d1cc2f2a5383f5e6d7dc6bd2
```

any idea or a better way?

Comment: Try to use the html parser for this kind of tasks. https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html

Comment: If the string is a valid HTML you nay use Beautiful Soup - https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html)

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class ValueFinder(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        for attr in attrs:
            if attr[0] == "value":
                print(attr[1])

parser = ValueFinder()
parser.feed('<input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="7629b234d1cc2f2a5383f5e6d7dc6bd2">')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search):

```
import re
string= '<input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="7629b234d1cc2f2a5383f5e6d7dc6bd2">'
m = re.search('value="(.+)?"',string)[1]
print(m)
```

Output:

```
629b234d1cc2f2a5383f5e6d7dc6bd2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regular expression

```
import re

match = re.compile(r'(value=\"(.*)\"\>)$').finditer(string)

for i in  match:
    print(i.group(2))
```

Output:

```
7629b234d1cc2f2a5383f5e6d7dc6bd2
```